# How to read a first character from the last line of a file in python

Tags: python

I am writing a scoreboard thingie in python (I am fairly new to the language). Basically user inputs their name and I want the program to read the file to determine, the number that the user is assigned to.

- For example, the names in the .txt file are:
- Num   Name      Score
- 1. John Doe    3
- 2. Mitch       5
- 3. Jane        1

How do I now add user no.4 without the user typing the exact string to write, only their name.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this the same as knowing how many lines in a file - apart from the column headings i.e. the number is just one more for each line?

Comment: keep this number in other file. Or keep lines without this numbers - you don't need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest rethinking your design - you probably don't need the line numbers in the file, however you could just read the file and see how many lines there are.

This won't scale if you end up with a lot of data.

```
>>> with open("data.txt") as f:
...   l = list(f)
...
```

This reads your header

```
>>> l
['Num Name Score\n', 'John Doe 3\n', 'Mitch 5\n', 'Jane 1\n']
>>> len(l)
4
```

So `len(l)-1` is the last number, and `len(l)` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to get the number of lines is by using `readlines()`

```
x=open("scoreboard.txt", "r")
line=x.readlines()
lastlinenumber= len(line)-1
x.close()

with open('scoreboard.txt', 'a') as scoreboard: #FIle is opened for appending
username = input("Enter your name!")
scoreboard.write(str(lastlinenumber) + '. ' + str(username) + ":  " + '\n')
scoreboard.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def add_user():
with open('scoreboard.txt', 'r') as scoreboard: 
    #Reads the file to get the numbering of the next player.
    highest_num = 0
    for line in scoreboard:
        number = scoreboard.read(1)
        num = 0
        if number == '':
            num == 1
        else:
            num = int(number)
        if num > highest_num:
            highest_num = num
    highest_num += 1

with open('scoreboard.txt', 'a') as scoreboard: #FIle is opened for appending
    username = input("Enter your name!")
    scoreboard.write(str(highest_num) + '. ' + str(username) + ":  " + '\n')
    scoreboard.close()
```

Thank you guys, I figured it out. This is my final code for adding a new user to the list.